# How can I programmatically add a websocket endpoint in embedded tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

I've been trying for weeks to get websockets working with embedded tomcat. I've tried emulating the examples in the tomcat unit tests to no avail. This is the first time I've tried to use websockets so I'm likely making a foolish mistake. Does anyone have any simple "Echo" examples for embedded tomcat websockets?

```
public void run() {

    if(!new File(consoleAppBase).isDirectory())
    {
         consoleAppBase = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString() + File.separatorChar + "wepapp";
    }

    tomcat = new Tomcat();

    tomcat.getService().removeConnector(tomcat.getConnector()); // remove default
    tomcat.getService().addConnector(createSslConnector(ConfigManager.getWeb_securePort())); // add secure option

    StandardServer server = (StandardServer) tomcat.getServer();
    AprLifecycleListener listener = new AprLifecycleListener();
    server.addLifecycleListener(listener);

    try {
        SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
        constraint.setDisplayName("SSL Redirect Constraint");
        constraint.setAuthConstraint(true);
        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
        collection.addPattern("/*");
        constraint.addAuthRole("administrator");
        constraint.addCollection(collection);

        //create the console webapp.
        consoleContext = tomcat.addWebapp(consoleContextPath, consoleAppBase);
        consoleContext.addConstraint(constraint);

        //this allows that little login popup for the console webapp.
        LoginConfig loginConfig = new LoginConfig();
        loginConfig.setAuthMethod("BASIC");
        consoleContext.setLoginConfig(loginConfig);
        consoleContext.addSecurityRole("administrator");

        //this creates a valid user.
        tomcat.addUser(ConfigManager.getWeb_username(), Encryptor.decrypt(ConfigManager.getWeb_passwordEncrypted()));
        tomcat.addRole("admin", "administrator");

    } catch (ServletException e) {
        LogMaster.getWebServerLogger().error("Error launching Web Application. Stopping Web Server.");
        LogMaster.getErrorLogger().error("Error launching Web Application. Stopping Web Server.", e);
        return;
    }

    addServlets(); // this is where I usually call a convenience method to add servlets

    // How can I add websocket endpoints instead?

}
```

Comment: Code from my answer worked well only on Tomcat 8.

Comment: I was able to get it to work in Tomcat 7 with your help. Much appreciated

Comment: It works from about Tomcat 7.0.41 or 42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using WebSocket in such way:

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
//...

@ServerEndpoint("/move")
public class TestWebSocketEndPoint {//@OnMessage 
public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {}
private static final Queue<Session> QUEUE = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Session>();

@OnOpen
public void open(Session session) {
    QUEUE.add(session);
}

@OnError
public void error(Session session, Throwable t) {
    StaticLogger.log(TestWebSocketEndPoint.class, t);
    QUEUE.remove(session);
}

@OnClose
public void closedConnection(Session session) {
    QUEUE.remove(session);
}

public static void sendToAll(String message) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Session> closedSessions = new ArrayList<Session>();
    for (Session session : QUEUE) {
        if (!session.isOpen()) {
            closedSessions.add(session);
        } else {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        }
    }
    QUEUE.removeAll(closedSessions);
}
}
```

And JS call:

```
var webSocket;
webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8585/test/move");
webSocket.onmessage = function () {
    alert('test');
}
```

Java call:

```
  TestWebSocketEndPoint.sendToAll(result);
```

Comment: This is not programmatically adding an endpoint, this is an annotated endpoint which is added automatically by the `ServerContainer`.

Answer (score 3):

For programmatic (non-annotated) endpoints, you have to provide a class that implements `Endpoint` to act as the server end, and then either:

1. Deploy a class that implements `ServerApplicationConfig` in your WAR file, that supplies `EndpointConfig` information about some or all of the non-annotated `Endpoint` instances that were found in the WAR file, or
2. Call `ServerContainer.addEndpoint()` during the deployment phase of your webapp.

See the Java™ API for WebSocket, JSR 356.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, configuring a websocket is the same as configuring a servlet (or a servlet filter). In web.xml you must include `<async-supported>true</async-supported>`.

I assume there's a similar flag in the java config.

Comment: Configuring a WebSocket is not the same as configuring a servlet or servlet filter; `async-supported` isn't required for Servlets, let alone WebSocket endpoints; and in any case this is not a programmatic solution.